# How do I return a SyntaxError to the user in python?

Tags: python, syntax-error

I'm working on a project that requires me to return a syntax error,

I've tried all of these: `SyntaxError("error")`, `return SyntaxError("error")`, and `new SyntaxError("error")`

Every time I tried to return one of these, it would just do nothing. I know how to do this in Javascript and am new to python. Is there a way that I can get a syntax error to be returned? If so, how?

Comment: "I'm working on a project that requires me to return a syntax error, I've tried all of these:" - did you try putting `python return a syntax error` [into a search engine](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=python+return+a+syntax+error)? "Pardon me if this is just me being stupid but every time I tried to return one of these it would just do nothing." The first two absolutely do something, you just can't observe the effect in the specific way that you expected to. Python does not have anything like `new`, though.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel The top post there is this one, now :)

Comment: Aside from that, though, **it does not ordinarily make sense** to use `SyntaxError` like this. Its purpose is for **Python itself**, to indicate a problem **in your code, that prevents it from making sense**. It should only be used in your code, if the purpose of your code is to take in more Python code from the user and do something with it.

Comment: @OneCricketeer so it goes. However, people [should at least be expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) to look at the titles of a page worth of results, see what seems investigating, and try investigating.

Answer (score 0):

`return` just returns the value from a function. Errors are regular objects in Python; constructing them doesn't cause a failure. If you literally want to "return" one; that's correct.

The `raise` keyword is Python's way to **throw** an error, halt execution and "*return control to the parent process*". Similarly to `throw new Error("error")` in NodeJS.

`SyntaxError` should be specific to the Python interpreter, however. Documentation would suggest that you `raise ValueError('Invalid Syntax')` for a parser of your own.